# Select the data from between two timestamp in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe, timestamp

My query is regrading getting the data, given two timestamp in python.

I need to have a input field, where i can enter the two timestamp, then from the CSV read, i need to retrieve for that particular input.

Actaul Data(CSV)

```
      Daily_KWH_System  PowerScout  Temperature         Timestamp  Visibility    Daily_electric_cost   kW_System 
 0         4136.900384  P371602077           0  07/09/2016 23:58          0    180.657705            162.224216 
 1         3061.657187  P371602077          66  08/09/2016 23:59         10    133.693074            174.193804 
 2         4099.614033  P371602077          63  09/09/2016 05:58         10    179.029562            162.774013  
3          3922.490275  P371602077          63  10/09/2016 11:58         10    171.297701            169.230047  
4          3957.128982  P371602077          88  11/09/2016 17:58         10    172.806125            164.099307
```

Example:

```
Input:
start date : 2-1-2017
end date :10-1-2017
```

Output

```
Timestamp     Value
2-1-2017      10
3-1-2017      35
.
.
.
.
10-1-2017     25
```

The original CSV would contain all the data

```
Timestamp        Value
1-12-2016        10
2-12-2016        25
.
.
.
1-1-2017         15
2-1-2017         10
.
.
.
10-1-2017        25
.
.
31-1-2017        50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `pd.read_csv` to read the file

```
df = pd.read_csv('my.csv', index_col='Timestamp', parse_dates=[0])
```

Then use your inputs to slice

```
df[start_date:end_date]
```

Comment: The format of timestamp is "26/09/2016 23:58". hence its throwing a Keyerror. 
KeyError: Timestamp('2016-12-02 00:00:00')

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need `dayfirst=True` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with select by `[]` if all start and end dates are in `df.index`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""Timestamp;Value
1-12-2016;10
2-12-2016;25
1-1-2017;15
2-1-2017;10
10-1-2017;25
31-1-2017;50"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
#if necessary add sep
#index_col=[0] convert first column to index
#parse_dates=[0] parse first column to datetime
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=";", index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True)
print (df)
            Value
Timestamp        
2016-12-01     10
2016-12-02     25
2017-01-01     15
2017-01-02     10
2017-01-10     25
2017-01-31     50

print (df.index.dtype)
datetime64[ns]

print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2016-12-01', '2016-12-02', '2017-01-01', '2017-01-02',
               '2017-01-10', '2017-01-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Timestamp', freq=None)
```

---

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2-1-2017', dayfirst=True)
end_date  = pd.to_datetime('10-1-2017', dayfirst=True)
print (df[start_date:end_date])
            Value
Timestamp        
2017-01-02     10
2017-01-10     25
```

If some dates are not in index you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime('3-1-2017', dayfirst=True)
end_date  = pd.to_datetime('10-1-2017', dayfirst=True)

print (df[(df.index > start_date) & (df.index > end_date)])
            Value
Timestamp        
2017-01-31     50
```

Comment: The format of timestamp is "26/09/2016 23:58". hence its throwing a Keyerror. 
KeyError: Timestamp('2016-12-02 00:00:00')

Comment: `print (df[start_date:end_date])` or `print (df[(df.index > start_date) & (df.index > end_date)])` ?

Comment: If first and data are in index try `print (df[str(start_date):str(end_date)])`

Comment: Ok, what return `print (df.index.dtype)` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to change its datetype. Since its throwing an error " Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'"

print (df.index.dtype) = this is saying df is an object

Comment: Ok, so you use parameters `index_col` and `parse_dates` in `read_csv` ?

Comment: python counts from `0`, so if need select first column to DatatimeIndex need `index_col=[0]` and `parse_dates=[0]`, if position is different, please change it.

Comment: I'll update the actual dataset in the question. Please let me know how to go about it

Comment: How does work `index_col=[3] and parse_dates=[3]` or `index_col=[4] and parse_dates=[4]` for select fourth or fifth columns ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134360/discussion-between-anagha-and-jezrael).